# How do i execute a stored procedure with a parameterised output from within another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

Consider the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Administration.SetAndRetrieveNewPurchaseOrderNumber 
    @PurchaseOrderNumber INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   UPDATE Administration.KeyNumbers
   SET PurchaseOrderNumber += 1
   WHERE RowId = 1

   SET @PurchaseOrderNumber = (SELECT kn.PurchaseOrderNumber
                               FROM Administration.KeyNumbers kn
                               WHERE kn.RowId = 1)
END
GO
```

I can use this easily from within my application by simply executing the procedure and passing in by reference a suitably named parameter.

I now find myself wanting to execute the procedure listed above in another stored procedure. I tried the following, but it doesn't appear to work (either with or without the @ symbol in the parameter part of the stored procedure being called;

```
DECLARE @PurchaseOrderNumber INT
EXEC Administration.SetAndRetrieveNewPurchaseOrderNumber(@PurchaseOrderNumber)
```

What is the correct way to do this, or in reality should there be a separate procedure for use in circumstances like this that only produces a scalar result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the output keyword when passing in the parameter.

For example:

```
Declare @output int;

Exec storedproc(@parameter output)
```